# Передача нескольких переменных в представление

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

Для рендера вида мне нужно передать несколько переменных из контроллера и "поймать" их уже там.
В контроллере:

```
return $this->render('index', array('arrayProvider'=>$arrayProvider,
            'message'=>$message,
            'smLaTi'=>$smLaTi ));
```

Переменные заполняются правильно, данные есть.

Как в представлении разделить этот $this на нужные мне переменные в представлении?

```
<?php
...
$this->message=$message;
$this->smLaTi=$smLaTi;
?>
```

arrayProvider принимается правильно в виджете gridview, а вот с оставшимися переменными у меня проблема. Ошибка:
Getting unknown property: yii\web\View::smLaTi

Comment: А также: можно ли добавить переменные в уже отрендеренный вид?
Внутри самого представления и не нарушая MVC

Comment: `Как в представлении разделить этот $this на нужные мне переменные в представлении?` - что значит разделить переменные? Они и так уже разделены . Зачем вы пишите `$this->message=$message;` ? Для чего?..`можно ли добавить переменные в уже отрендеренный вид?` - а это что значит?

Comment: По хорошему, чтобы передать "несколько" переменных в представление, есть такая штука - называется `ViewModel` - т е это класс модели, в котором выбраны поля сугубу для представления (Не путайте с Model в MVC).

Comment: "Зачем вы пишите $this->message=$message; ? Для чего?"
Как написать правильно?
Про разделить я выразился совсем некорректно. Для рендера index я отправил несколько(3) переменных.
Как их правильно можно использовать в представлении?

Comment: "можно ли добавить переменные в уже отрендеренный вид? - а это что значит?"
Если в контроллере уже до этого экшена был создан вид index. 
Можно ли другим экшеном его дополнить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В представлении `$this` указывает на объект `yii\web\View` в контексте которого происходит отрисовка. Раз тут ООП - то это и логично, что у всего своя ответственность.

В целом, в представлении, чтобы воспользоваться переданными переменными, достаточно просто обратиться к ним по указанному имени, без `$this`:

```
<?= $message; ?>
<?= $smLaTi; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я в начале своего пути по yii2 и php.
И именно это я и написал в самом начале работы над этим делом (часа 4 назад). 
И, видимо, я упустил что-то совсем небольшое и незаметное и это не сработало изначально.
Теперь всё прекрасно функционирует. И это ведь так просто и очевидно!

П.С. Со своей небольшой репутацией я не могу пока что поставить вам +1

Comment: @Pvokinsark просто посмотрите какие-нибудь начальные видео курсы по yii2. А только потом приступайте к делу. Тода будет попроще. Ведь в любых уроках есть основы. В т.ч. и то, что описано выше